# "DISTINCT ON" with HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am trying to get distinct values from table `application` based on the column `entry_id`. I've managed to get this working with plain SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.entry_id) a.* FROM application AS a 
JOIN entry AS e ON e.id = a.entry_id
WHERE e.valid_until BETWEEN ? AND ?;
```

The problem is, I have to translate it to HQL. Is there any way to resolve it in HQL without Criteria API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [this feature](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2800) has been requested a long time ago but is still unresolved.